# How do I give the ENTER keypress?

Tags: teensy, keyboard, terminal

I have a Teensy set up as a keyboard, joystick, and I'm giving keyboard commands. Letter and number keys are going fine. But when I try sending ENTER, I get some extra code in my Linux terminal:

```
$ 16424
16424: command not found
```

the code I have to give the ENTER key goes like this:

```cpp
void setup() {
  pinMode(0, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // read the digital inputs and set the buttons
  Joystick.button(1, digitalRead(0));
  Serial.println(digitalRead(0));
  if(digitalRead(0)==0){
    Keyboard.println(KEY_ENTER);
  }
  delay(50);
}
```

where is this  "16424" coming from, and how do I send an ENTER keypress?
I am using a Teensy 2.0, on Linux, with Arduino IDE 1.6.7.

Comment: Keyboard.println((char) KEY_ENTER); might be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just "print" a key like that. You use `print` for sending text.

When you use `println` it sends an enter key along with your text, so you can do :

```
Keyboard.println("ls -al");
```

and it will send the text `ls -al` and press enter for you.

If you want to do it in the 'raw' way you will need to press and then release the key:

```
Keyboard.press(KEY_ENTER);
Keyboard.release(KEY_ENTER);
```